# Ruby server provisioning tool

Tags: ruby, provisioning

I'm looking for a server provisioning tool, hopefully in Ruby, that fits in the gap between tools like Kickstart and tools like Chef.

I need something that can connect over SSH and set up users, keys, install tools, etc.  Something that can go from an empty OS to a working Chef instance, at least.

I've been experimenting with mass.pl (http://lerp.com/~sic/mass/) but it doesn't look like it's actively maintained, and it looks like a big learning investment, so I want to know if there's other stuff out there before I spend a lot of time with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [sprinkle](http://redartisan.com/2008/5/27/sprinkle-intro) and [capistrano](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I had to hack sprinkle to allow SSL with a password, but it looks like it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/technicalpickles/moonshine